# How do nested loop communicate with each other?

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop, nested

In below Question after entering into 2nd for-loop (for(int j=0;j<=5;j++)) does count have to follow the condition stated inside the while loop?

```
public class MyClass {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
           int count=1;
           for(int i=1;i<=5;i++){
              while(count%2!=0){
                 for(int j=0;j<=5;j++){
                    i=i+1; 
                    j=j+1;
                    count++;
                    System.out.println(+count);
                 }
              }
           }
        }
}
```

Comment: I don't quite know what "does count follows condition stated inside while loop" is supposed to mean. The inner loop will run until it is finished, then return to the outer loop which might then decide to either run again, triggering another run of the inner loop, or continue...

Comment: Where is the multithreads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using proper indentation always helps understanding the code better (if you are in Eclipse, this can be done by holding down the ctrl and shift keys, then pressing F).

The second for-loop will keep running and counting 'count' up untill 'j' is <= 5, and then when the loop in finished, the condition inside your while loop will be checked again. If this is still true, the second for-loop will run again

Answer (score 0):

It will first execute the complete (2nd) for-loop and will check the condition of the while loop after completion of this for-loop. Count is 4 when the for-loop is finished, which does not meet the condition from the while and therefore it will not execute the for-loop again